# How to multi update && insert intent in dialogFlow CX?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

For the ES version, we are using the batchUpdate method in the googleapis module to perform bulk updates. However, for the CX version, we are using the @google-cloud/dialogflow-cx module and there doesn't seem to be a method for bulk adding, modifying, or deleting intents.

Is it not possible to perform bulk operations in the CX version? And if not, does CX not have the ability to import and export intents as files like the ES version does?